# Padronização na construção de api Rest com Vraptor

Tags: java, rest, vraptor

Bom estou com uma dúvida sobre a padronização na criação de endpoints rest.
Segundo a documentação do Vraptor eu posso definir o path da requisição usando a anotação > `@Path("/paciente-api")`  *aqui na empresa esse é o padrão* , mas tenho notado algumas classes em que o path termina com / , que diferença isso faria no fim?
As requisições também são anotadas, por exemplo> `@Get("/")`,
 **aqui é onde vai minha maior questão**, 
seguindo essa lógica minha requisição seria um GET para localhost:8080/sistema/paciente-api/ , ate ai tudo ok, mas quando eu tenho que enviar parâmetros o STATUS CODE é 405, porque isso acontece é um erro no meu backend ou da requisição ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isaías, essa questão do path, se você coloca a barra no final, deverá usar com a barra onde você chamar. Ou seja, se você tem a anotação com `@Path("/paciente-api")`, lá na requisição deveria ser `http://localhost:8080/sistema/paciente-api`.

Mas na documentação do vraptor tem um cookbook para aceitar ser com ou sem barra, segue o link http://www.vraptor.org/pt/cookbook/aceitando-urls-com-ou-sem-barra-no-final/

Assim como `/` letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas diferenciam também, por isso nos meus paths, nunca uso `/` no final e letras maiúsculas.

Provavelmente deu 405 porque tinha alguma outra rota @Post ou tal para este caminho com `/` no final, posso ajudar mais com essa parte se você der mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu notei que a requisição ignorava o / quando ia com parâmetros, deixando a url assim :
http://localhost:8080/sistema/paciente-api?nome=xxx , 
quando eu coloco o / no final do path a requisição encontra o seu caminho.
mas fico com essa dúvida sobre as boas práticas na hora de criar uma api rest. 
Onde está o meu erro, na documentação que deveria ter sido clara, ou na padronização do endereço, com ou sem /, entende?

Comment: Isso nem chega ser tanto do VRaptor, porque sempre que a gente fala de REST, estamos basicamente falando disso. REST normalmente vamos usar os métodos corretos de HTTP (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), mas o VRaptor, por experiencia própria, entende muito bem GET e POST, então me viro só com eles. No geral, se não quero atualizar informação uso get, se não uso post.

Comment: Quanto as rotas eu uso, por exemplo: 
(get) /usuarios - listar usuarios
(get) /usuarios/1 - detalhar usuario
(post) /usuarios - criar usuario
(get) /usuarios/1/editar - atualizar usuario 
(post) /usuarios/editar - atualizar usuario (aqui seria put, mas vraptor tem que passar um parametro extra para ser put, isso dá problema quando envia arquivo, por isso nunca uso)
(get ) /usuarios/1/remover - remover usuario

Comment: se eu preciso pegar os grupos de um usuário eu vou usar rota /usuarios/1/grupos e por aí vai... não sei se estou chegando na parte que você está questionando, qualquer coisa me fala

Answer (score 2):

**1. Você anota seu método com:**

> As requisições também são anotadas, por exemplo> @Get("/")

**2. Tenta enviar parâmetros na requisição e recebe o status 405 na resposta:**

> mas quando eu tenho que enviar parâmetros o STATUS CODE é 405

---

- Aparentemente está tentando realizar um **POST** em um método que espera uma requisição do tipo **GET**. Tente alterar a anotação do seu método de `@Get("/")` para `@Post("/")`.

Dê uma olhada na documentação a respeito dos [métodos de requisição HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) e [códigos de status de respostas HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).